# Drivers / Constraints resourses usage

Tags: scripting, rigging, constraints, drivers, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the rig of a cartoon creature, and this rig has really large amount of bones (more than 400) to have all the abilities according to the plot. I have IK/FK chains, Stretch To chains and all of its combinations. Tons of constraints, and all this staff really freezes viewport and render. And I know that many constraints can be substituted for drivers. So, the question is what consumes more computing resources: drivers or constraints? Or may be this just doesn't matter?
I am really stuck with this, I cannot just delete sone bones, I need to make them work faster with any approach. Probably you can tell me what are the haviest things (constraints, drivers etc) in rig for CPU
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to evaluate the performance of the rig just on its own? Without any mesh? I doubt the bottleneck is in drivers or constraints.

Comment: Hello, @Jaroslav. Yes, you are right, I also have meshes (totally 54k vertices in Subsurf level 2 view, I don't think that is too much) with many modifiers (especially Shrinkwrap), but as long as I cannot delete modifiers (there's no Shrinkwrap substitute, because Boolean consumes even more), I try to do something with my rig. Just to make it as much efficient as it can be. It has may Action constraints, so my fear that all these constraints are hard for PC to recalculate at each frame. But probably drivers are not less heard